# How to disable window asking for permission to make changes on your device

Tags: windows, electron, electron-builder

I have developed an electron app and created an installer using electron-builder.

Every time I run the app, windows asks for permission for allowing the app to make changes on my device.

How can I disable that?
Is it happening because of some signing problem of the electron app?

Comment: It seems like you're touching some system paths (like `C:\Program Files` or similar). What are the app paths?

Comment: C:\Users\SunSo\AppData\Local\Programs\app-name

Comment: @Grzegorz please help.